# Is Nikon AF Nikkor 28-80mm Lens compatible with Nikon D5100 DSLR?

Tags: dslr, camera-basics, nikon-d5100, compatibility, dx

I plan to buy the Nikon AF Zoom-Nikkor 28-80mm f/3.3-5.6G lens for my Nikon D5100. I want to know compatibility, performance and quality of the lens-D5100 combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems autofocus is not supported for this combination.

Nikon has the following resources with additional information:

- [Which NIKKOR Lens Type is Right for Your DSLR?](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/which-nikkor-lens-type-is-right-for-your-dslr.html)
- [Lens Compatibility Chart](https://www.nikonusa.com/Images/Learn-Explore/Photography-Techniques/2011/Which-Nikkor-is-Right-for-You/Media/NIKKOR-lens-compatibility-chart.pdf) (pdf)

Answer (score 4):

This lens uses a screw driven AF, meaning the body drives the AF. The D5xxx series and D3xxx series of cameras need AF-S lenses in order to AF with them.